# Enable Bootstraps 5 responsive font size (rfs) for base font tags

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, responsive, bootstrap-5

I am trying to enable Bootstrap's RFS feature in v5.1.3 for basis font tags globally.

In my SCSS i have set some basic font-sizes, include the bootstrap scss files and set the font-size include. But in the compiled CSS the font sizes are still in rem only.

The SCSS:

```
//Fonts
$font-size-root: 20px;
$font-size-base: 1rem;
$enable-responsive-font-sizes: true;
$enable-rfs: true;
$h1-font-size: $font-size-root * 1.8;
$h2-font-size: $font-size-root * 1.5;
$h3-font-size: $font-size-root * 1;
$h4-font-size: $font-size-root * 0.75;
$h5-font-size: $font-size-root * 0.5;
$h6-font-size: $font-size-root * 0.25;
$small-font-size: $font-size-root * 0.75;
$font-sizes: (
    1: $h1-font-size,
    2: $h2-font-size,
    3: $h3-font-size,
    4: $h4-font-size,
    5: $h5-font-size,
    6: $h6-font-size,
    7: $small-font-size,
);
@import "Boostrap/bootstrap.scss";
body {
    @include font-size($font-size-base);
    //border-style: solid;
    h1 {
        @include font-size($h1-font-size);
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    h2 {
        @include font-size($h2-font-size);
    }
    h3 {
        @include font-size($h3-font-size);
    }
    h4 {
        @include font-size($h4-font-size);
    }
    h5 {
        @include font-size($h5-font-size);
    }
    h6 {
        @include font-size($h6-font-size);
    }
    p {
        @include font-size($font-size-root);
    }
    .btn {
        @include font-size($btn-font-size);
    }
}
```

But the compiled CSS looks like this:

```
body {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
body h1, body .h1 {
  font-size: calc(1.35rem + 1.2vw);
  font-weight: bold;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  body h1, body .h1 {
    font-size: 2.25rem;
  }
}
body h2, body .h2 {
  font-size: calc(1.3125rem + 0.75vw);
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  body h2, body .h2 {
    font-size: 1.875rem;
  }
}
body h3, body .h3 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
body h4, body .h4 {
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
}
body h5, body .h5 {
  font-size: 0.625rem;
}
body h6, body .h6 {
  font-size: 0.3125rem;
}
body p {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
body .btn {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Am I missing something or did i get the complete idea of this feature wrong?
What bothers me the most is the p-tag. It isn't responsive at all.

Comment: I see only (at)media (min-width: 1200px) {} maybe you need other sizes too. Such like: (at)media (min-width:320px) { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */
}

Answer (score 1):

I have different sizes for different devices. Maybe there are better solutions.
Tell me. But this solution works.

Example:

```
@media (min-width:320px) { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */
    h1 {
        font-size: 3rem;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    }

    h4 {
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 1.1rem;
    }

    h5, h6 {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    h6 {
        font-style: italic;
    }
}
```

and:

```
@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */
    h1 {
        font-size: 6rem;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 4rem;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 3rem;
        padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    }

    h4 {
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 1.1rem;
    }

    h5, h6 {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    h6 {
        font-style: italic;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well as i do understand RFS should make this obsolete